# PyQt & QtSql databases - problems with custom connection and QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtsql

I'm trying to make a table to view database, as a part of the bigger project. Te whole project utilises many databases and connections, so I must use custom connection names to manage them all.

The problem is, despite fact, that database is opening and file seems to be generated properly, I cant view it in QSqlTableModel table, documentation is not helping too much.

Here are scripts:

**database.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5 import QtSql


def createConnection():
    """Create and open a database connection."""
    connection = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE", "conkon")
    connection.setDatabaseName("contacts.sqlite")
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(connection)
    if connection.open():
        query.exec(
           """
           CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (
               short VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
               fullname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
               NIP VARCHAR(50),
               postcode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
               city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
               street VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
               phone VARCHAR(50),
               email VARCHAR(40),
               discount INTEGER,
               comment VARCHAR(40)
           )
           """
       )
```

**model.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql

class ContactsModel():
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = self._createModel()

    @staticmethod
    def _createModel():
        tableModel = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(None, QtSql.QSqlDatabase.database("contacts.sqlite"))
        tableModel.setTable("contacts")
        tableModel.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        tableModel.select()
        headers = ("Skrót", "Pełna Nazwa", "NIP", "Kod pocztowy", "Miejscowość", "Ulica", "Telefon", "Email", "Rabat", "Komentarz" )
        for columnIndex, header in enumerate(headers):
            tableModel.setHeaderData(columnIndex, Qt.Horizontal, header)
            return tableModel
```

**fragment of window declaration form views.py**

```
    """Main Window."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializer."""
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MOJManager")
        self.resize(1000, 250)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.contactsModel = ContactsModel()
        self.setupUI()

   def setupUI(self):
        """Setup the main window's GUI."""
        # Create the table view widget
        self.table = QTableView()
        self.table.setModel(self.contactsModel.model)
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        # Create buttons
        self.addButton = QPushButton("Dodaj")
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.openAddDialog)
        self.deleteButton = QPushButton("Usuń")
        self.deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.deleteContact)
        self.clearAllButton = QPushButton("Wyczyść wszystko")
        self.clearAllButton.clicked.connect(self.clearContacts)
        # Lay out the GUI
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.deleteButton)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.clearAllButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.layout.addLayout(layout)
```

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from .database import createConnection
from .views import WindowKontakty


def mainKont():
    """RP Contacts main function."""
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   # Connect to the database before creating any window
    createConnection()
    # Create the main window if the connection succeeded
    winMag = WindowKontakty()
    winMag.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    return winMag
```

The problem is, there are no errors displayed anywhere (, database seems to be opened. I can't populate it from the table view, only with queries. I see that the issue is propably with this database connection, but I cant find out where. Can anyone help figure out?

EDIT: I added code fragment with setModel() on views.py

Comment: Where are you setting the model on the table? And that return in the for loop seems to have a wrong indentation.

Comment: Here in init function in model 

        self.model = self._createModel()

Comment: that just creates the model. At some point, you should have a QTableView and call `setModel()` with that model. If you don't do it, how could the view know anything about the data it should show?

Comment: I've edited the post with the missing code fragment. It worked on default databases/connections.

Comment: @LGusti please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it lied in    `tableModel.setTable("contacts")` method, it should be adressed via connection, not the databasename. It woked when changed to

`tableModel.setTable("conkon")`

After this change, the table is generating properly.

Comment: Sorry, what?! What table is generating?